# TFS - How to overwrite files by using Checkout for edit?

Tags: .net, tfs, version-control

A wrong merge was made by 1 member of the team, but he didn't commit yet. He's working on a branch.

The current version of the TRUNK is correct, but when I merge from TRUNK to the BRANCH, it doesn't update the branch, since during the merge, a wrong version was selected as the correct one.

How can I fix this on branch?

I was thinking about "check out for edit" all the files of a project, like overwriting all lines, so when I try to update the BRANCH from the TRUNK, the merge would happen again, but when I did it, it throws this error:

> All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server.

Comment: Its not clear exactly what has happened. The team member merged from the trunk to their branch? and they haven't checked that merge in? and you are now trying to do the same merge and the changes are not being detected by TFS because it thinks they are already merged? Need some more detail to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, since the wrong merge hasn't committed. You can discard changesets from this merge with this  `tf merge /discard`  command.

> **/discard**
>   Does not perform the merge operation, but updates the
>   merge history to track that the merge occurred. This discards a
>   changeset from being used for a particular merge.

An example discards changeset 137 as a candidate for merging into branch2 :

```
c:\projects>tf merge /discard /version:C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
```

More details about the command you can refer the link from MSDN: [Merge Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy.aspx)

---

Update

Since there have been a merge process in the branch. It's impossible to overwrite the original merge with a new merge. You have to either discard the merge or commit the merge. If you discard the merger, you can committer the new feature to the main branch directly. If you commit the merge, since a wrong version was selected as the correct, you can choose `Selected changesets` during the merge .If you selected `Selected changesets`, then the Select changesets to merge into the target branch page appears. Select the changeset you want to merge.

Comment: I can't simply discard the changes, because a new feature is already being implemented on this branch :P. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Since there have been a merge process in the branch. It's impossible to overwrite the original merge with a new merge. You have to either discard the merge or commit the merge.  If you discard the merger, you can committer the new feature to the main branch directly.   If you commit the merge, since a wrong version was selected as  the correct, you can choose`Selected changesets`during the merge .If you selected `Selected changesets`, then the Select changesets to merge into the target branch page appears. Select the changeset you want to merge.